# Cannot find Symbol MenuItem

Tags: java

I'm writing a code where I have an ArrayList input and from that ArrayList I have to get two numbers from that and subtract them. When I'm doing this I get a Cannot find Symbol error. Why am I getting this error?

```
public static double[] profits( ArrayList<MenuItem> items )
{
 double[] lol = new double[items.size()];
 for ( MenuItem z : items )
  {
     for ( int i = 0; i < lol.length  ; i++ )
      {
        lol[i] = roundMoney(getPrice() - getCost());
      }
    return lol;
  }
}
```

this is the main class:

```
     ArrayList<MenuItem> items = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();
    items.add( new MenuItem( "Alliteration Armadillo", 20.25, 3.15, 1, true ) );
    items.add( new MenuItem( "Consonance Chameleon", 5.45, 0.75, 0, false ) );
    items.add( new MenuItem( "Assonance Bass", 1.95, 0.50, 1, false ) );

    double[] t = profits( items );

    for ( double d : t )
      System.out.print( printAmount( d ) + " " );
```

What my output is supposed to be is a array of doubles that should output {17.10 4.70 1.45}

```
The error says:

TC1.java:17: cannot find symbol 

symbol  : method getPrice()

If this isn't enough information then here is the whole class:

public class MenuItem 
{ 
  private String myName; 

  private double myPrice, 
                 myCost; 

  private int    myCode; 

  private boolean myAvailability; 

  public MenuItem( String name, double price, double cost, int code, boolean available ) 
  { 
    myName = name; 
    myPrice = price; 
    myCost = cost; 
    myCode = code; 
    myAvailability = available; 
  } 

  public String getName() { return myName; } 
  public double getPrice() { return myPrice; } 
  public double getCost() { return myCost; } 
  public int getCode() { return myCode; } 
  public boolean available() { return myAvailability; } 

  // Create your method here 
  public String menuString() 
  { 
  return getName() + " ($" + getPrice() + ")"; 
  } 

  public static double roundMoney( double amount ) 
  { 
    return (int)(100 * amount + 0.5) / 100.0; 
  } 

  public static String printAmount( double d ) 
  { 
    String s = "" + d; 
    int k = s.indexOf( "." ); 
    if ( k < 0 ) 
      return s + ".00"; 
    if ( k + 1 == s.length() ) 
      return s + "00"; 
    if ( k + 2 == s.length() ) 
      return s + "0"; 
    else 
      return s; 
  } 
}
```

F

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first code snippet, replace `getPrice()` and `getCost()` with `z.getPrice()` and `z.getCost()`.

Now, to get the output you wanted, fix the first snippet to have:

```
public static double[] profits(ArrayList<MenuItem> items)
{
    double[] lol = new double[items.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (MenuItem z : items)
    {
        lol[i] = roundMoney(z.getPrice() - z.getCost());
        i++;
    }
    return lol;
}
```

Comment: Ok that worked but my out put ended up being 1.45 3 times. What do I have to do to make it 17.10 4.70 1.45?

Comment: The loop itself is wrong; I'll update my answer with the fix.

Comment: Oh I see, so the second for- loop wasn't necessary? Because of that for loop it kept asking me to have two return statements and that wasn't right.... Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah, the second for-loop was causing the second bug. You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to use the Object Reference Variable `z` of type `MenuItem` to access its method `getPrice()` and `getCost()`

Use `z` with **dot operator** to call the method.

**eg:**

`z.getPrice()` and `z.getCost()`